# Do I really need to know number theory?

Tags: number-theory, advice

I'm an avid math student and have delved into the world of calculus, differential equations, and analysis. Now I am faced with number theory, and it looks incredibly dull to me. It seems as though it has no hold in the real world (except cryptography; every article I've seen that mentions real-world applications of math mentions cryptography as the application of number theory)! Should I think about learning it because it ties in with other branches of math? Or is it really not that necessary to understand deep connections within mathematics?

Thanks.

Comment: "Now I am faced with number theory, and it looks incredibly dull to me."  I suspect every branch of mathematics has problems that are interesting to some and onerous to others.  Should I ask how you came to be "faced with number theory" when you seem determined to dislike it so?

Comment: "Or is **what** really not that necessary"? Are you asking whether number theory is unnecessary to understanding deep connections in mathematics or whether an understanding of deep connections in mathematics is unnecessary.

Comment: At least learn enough number theory to be able to say you don't like it in a reasoned, mature way. As it is I suspect many people will have extremely negative reactions to your breezy dismissal based on little experience.

Comment: Over at mathoverflow, there is a post asking for [Pratical applications of algebraic number theory?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24971/practical-applications-of-algebraic-number-theory). I didn't study number theory in any depth, but I'm quite convinced that other branches of number theory allow for similar posts.

Answer (score 5):

> *Do I really need to know number theory ?*

- You don't “need” to know anything.
- Why the heck is number theory supposed to occupy a slave position with regard to the other branches of mathematics, and not the other way around ?

On related news, [almost all integers](http://oeis.org/A119748) can be written as the sum of a prime and a perfect power.